# Get parameters for HTML page embedded with object tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-object

Is it possible for an HTML file embedded with `<object>` to access the values of its `<param>`s?

I'm in the process of bring a legacy webapp current for my company, that is, make it HTML5-capable among other things. Until I get a proper templating engine (as well as a proper working tree structure and architecture, holy crap) integrated into this thing, I'm using the `<object>` tag to embed HTML pages to provide things like audio/video players.

I decided to use `<object>` rather than `<iframe>` because `<object>`s can contain `<param>` elements. And, especially for the A/V players, I'd like to be able to have configurable properties such as the media file to be played, whether certain buttons appear/are hidden, etc. Nothing in the Web API sticks out obviously to me (I am still looking), and I can't seem to find anything on whether it's possible to grab `<param>` values from the parent page (searching has gotten me a million results about using `<object>` and `<param>` with Flash, which is useless to me).

If this isn't possible, I suppose I'm better off using `<iframe>` and setting the `src` to a URL with a query string...

Comment: For your A/V player application, there's nothing stopping you from providing a dynamically generated URL to a <video> tag, if that helps.

Comment: The implementation of the A/V player uses jPlayer so the player interface is styleable - if that wasn't a requirement, I'd just be using `<audio>` and `<video>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/param.html), no. The param tag is only used when the object represents a plugin, which is probably why your searches (and mine) kept turning up results for Flash.